# Ошибка при создании собственного шаблонного тега в Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Согласно [учебнику](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/howto/custom-template-tags.html#inclusion-tags) создал свой тэг чтобы вывести дополнительную информацию.
Но информация не появляется. судя по всему игнорируется **hots_articles.html**

был создан файл **articles_extras.py** в templatetags в котором:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('articles/hots_articles.html')
def show_results(hot):
    # Тут что-то буде вычисляться
    pass
```

в основном шаблоне **main.html** была сделана точка внедрения шаблона

```
{% load articles_extras %}
```

и сам шаблон **hots_articles.html**

```
{% show_results hot %}
<p>Test</p>
```

Comment: Создали файл `__init__.py` в templatetags?

Comment: Да создал     `__init__.py`

Comment: apps в котором лежит templatetags включен в settings?

Comment: да. это приложение уже используется для вывода статей. Просто хотел добавить дополнительную колонку с самыми популярными постами.